# Answer improvement comments below answer -1

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer

Why user who down-votes the answer and adds comment bellow the answer, how he/she thinks the answer can be improved, would also give away one of his/her points?

**Main question:**

What do to when the user answers to his/her post himself, but the accepted answer is not an answer. Instead the answer is just a general speculation what is wrong and does not give anything to other forum members? Can anyone explain me please if the answer should be down voted or flagged? *[example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156668/magento-2-custom-shipping-carrier-validations-for-custom-field/156708#156708)*

*(Before down-voting current question please answer, what did you lear from the example by comment?)*

Comment: give  example then we can surely tell you what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem I think you can do down voting if you want to do so ,

you can not force someone to provide full detail answer because here question also asked by that person.

in this kind of case you can leave comment to OP that provide full answer but if he/she don't want to answer you can not do more except flag that post as  `low quality Post`, if community (Reviewer) feels the same answer would be deleted